# Почему в Typescript выдает ошибку при определении выходного типа?

Tags: typescript, generics

```
    export function keys<T extends object>(obj: T): (keyof T)[] {
  const currentKeys: string[] = [];

  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) currentKeys.push(key);
  }

  return currentKeys;
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '(keyof T)[]'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof T'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Нужно чтобы на выходе был массив из ключей этого объекта, и хоть ключи и строки всегда, нужно проверить что такой ключ вобще есть в объекте

Answer (score 1):

Нужно изменить тип возвращаемой переменной.

```
const currentKeys: string[] = [];
```

Так как возвращаются ключи объекта этот тип и надо указать

```
const currentKeys: (keyof T)[] = [];
```

Comment: Вообще да, так даже лучше. Более универсальное решение.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Answer (score 0):

> `<T extends object>`

Эта запись еще не гарантирует, что ключи объекта будут строковыми. Замените на `<T extends Record<string, unknown>>`.

Тип `Record<string, ...>` даст понять, что ожидается на вход объект, в котором ключи гарантированно будут строковыми.